# Anaconda's cuDNN for theano

Tags: anaconda, theano, cudnn

I have been following instructions [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/tensorflow-gpu-installation-made-easy-use-conda-instead-of-pip-52e5249374bc) on how to install tensorflow with GPU support on Anaconda. It also installs Cuda and cuDNN on Anaconda with it thus, simplifying the installation process.

I needed to replicate the process with theano. However, I am running into the following issue with cuDNN:

```
Can not use cuDNN on context None: cannot compile with cuDNN. We got this 
error:
b'In file included from /tmp/try_flags_c3rotdub.c:4:0:\n/data/home/me/.conda/envs/tf_gpu/include/cudnn.h:63:10: fatal error: driver_types.h: 
No such file or directory\n #include "driver_types.h"\n          
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\ncompilation terminated.\n'
Mapped name None to device cuda0: Tesla V100-PCIE-16GB (0000:00:06.0)
```

tf_gpu is the name my conda environment. I did not run into issues with Tensorflow and I do not have admin rights to the machine.